# Como adicionar uma imagem no menu?

Tags: python, wxwidgets

Preciso adicionar uma imagem no menu do meu programa em Python. Estou utilizando a biblioteca wxpython.
O menu está assim:

O código:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import wx


class Frame(wx.Frame):
    title = "SEA"
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title=self.title, size=(800, 600))
        self.panel1 = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.createMainPanel()
        self.createMainMenu()
        self.Centre()

    def createMainPanel(self, color=(0, 0, 0)):
        panel = wx.Panel(self, id=wx.ID_ANY, pos=(0, 0), size=self.GetSize())
        panel.SetBackgroundColour('GRAY')

class App(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.mainScreen = Frame()
        self.SetTopWindow(self.mainScreen)
        self.mainScreen.Show()

        return True  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App(False)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Quero adicionar a seguinte imagem no menu, na parte de cima, alinhada ao centro, que é esta:

Alguém pode me ajudar com isso? pesquisei o dia todo e não consegui. Seria melhor se fosse com botões de imagem, pois vou precisar adicionar outros depois.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja se este trecho lhe ajuda:

```
self.bitmap = wx.Bitmap('imagem.jpg')
        wx.EVT_PAINT(self, self.OnPaint)

        self.Centre()

    def OnPaint(self, event):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        dc.DrawBitmap(self.bitmap, 60, 20)
```

Retirei desse tuto [aqui parece bom](https://wiki.wxpython.org/AnotherTutorial)...

Vlw espero que ajude

Qualquer coisa vai comentando...

Comment: funcionou, o problema era o fundo cinza que coloquei, estava tampando a imagem. Obrigado!

Comment: @IvoQueiroz caso alguma das respostas estiver correta, poderia validá-la clicando no icon verde abaixo das setas de avaliação... Vlw...

Comment: obrigado! você sabe como posso posicionar essa imagem no menu?

Comment: Abre uma nova questão, as vezes outros usuários podem procurar por essa dúvida também, quando estiver formulando a pergunta, veja se já não tem alguma resposta...